# WooCommerce custom checkbox $_POST issue on checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've added a custom checkbox to my checkout page and  trying to get results onto order page. Below is what I've tried. When I submit an order it always results in "N/A" even if checked.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'add_checkout_sign_optout_policy', 9 );

function add_checkout_sign_optout_policy() {

woocommerce_form_field( 'nosign', array(
'type'          => 'checkbox',
'class'         => array('form-row nosign'),
'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for- checkbox checkbox'),
'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox'),
'required'      => false,
'label'         => 'I Opt-Out of Signature Upon Delivery and understand all <a href="" class="woocommerce-shipping-optout-link">Terms</a>.',
)); 

}

/* Save "Terms and Conditions" */

// 1. Save Opt-Out as Order Meta

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_optout_acceptance' 
);

function save_optout_acceptance( $order_id ) {
if ( $_POST['nosign'] ) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'nosign', esc_attr( $_POST['nosign'] ) );
}

// 2. Display Opt-Out Single Order Page 

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_optout_acceptance' );

function display_optout_acceptance( $order ) {
if ( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'nosign', true ) == 'on' ) {
    echo '<p><strong>Shipping Opt-Out: </strong>accepted</p>';
} else echo '<p><strong>Shipping Opt-Out: </strong>N/A</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
// 2. Display T&C @ Single Order Page 

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_optout_acceptance', 10, 1 );

function display_optout_acceptance( $order ) {
$nosignoptout = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'nosign', true );
if ( $nosignoptout == 1) {
    echo '<p><strong>Shipping Opt-Out: </strong>Selected</p>';
} else echo '<p><strong>Shipping Opt-Out: </strong>Not Selected</p>';
}
```